# Propiedad "max" de input number HTML desde controlador

Tags: java, html, spring

Tengo un `input` en mi `HTML`, y mi intención es que el valor de "**max**" venga en el `POST` desde el `@Controller`. La variable "**posible_rate**" llega al `HTML`, pero su valor en **max**, no tiene efecto.

¿Alguien tiene idea de por que no lo está pillando?

`JAVA`:

```
...
model.addAttribute("posible_rate", posible_rate);
...
```

`HTML`:

```
<input name="find_rate" type="number" class="form-control" min="1" max="$posible_rate" />
```

Comment: Estás usando Themeleaf?

Comment: Si, se me olvidó indicarlo, perdón.

Comment: @E.Betanzos tu pregunta me hizo resolverlo. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El problema era que estaba llamando de forma incorrecta al parámetro `posible_rate`:

```
<input name="find_rate" type="number" class="form-control" min="1" th:max="${posible_rate}" />
```